# Using NSIS, Is there a way to determine that a TextBox can only contain English and numbers?

Tags: nsis

Thanks for reading my article :] !

By adding OnChange function to TextBox, I am making a code that sets spaces for characters other than English and numbers. When inputting words other than English and numbers, is it possible to generate an Event?

Thank you :] !_!

Comment: Is the event important or do you just want to block everything that is not A-Z a-z 0-9 etc?

Comment: You can use OnChange to generate an event. How you use Regex matters.

Comment: I tried to use ${REMatches}, but even if dll is added or nsh is included, Invalid command: "${REAMtches}" is displayed, and if NSISpcre::REAMtches is used, an unknown value is returned.

Comment: I simply asked you if the event was important or if doing it without is acceptable and you failed to answer...